# Moving one add on website to a new cPanel host

Tags: hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting, transfer, server.transfer

For several years now I have freely hosted several local organizations web pages at no cost. One of those organizations wishes to move to their own server that they manage with their own server provider (alas, not A Small Orange--a little too expensive for them).

They have

- a couple add on domains/websites
- advanced DNS records with Google Apps
- several mailing lists
- a database or two
- and of course their hosting directory

I was just wondering if there is a way to just export that stuff, so it can be imported in another cPanel?

OPTION ONE: One by one move all the stuff to the new host. Create the mailing lists, manually import the databases, set up the DNSs, and upload the files.

OPTION TWO: I could export the entire site, download the entire site, go to the new provider and upload it, and then delete all my content.

OPTION THREE: Is it possible to export their parts of the site, and import that to the other hosts cPanel?

Or another option all together? No email, and I don't even need the hosting history to be there (but it would be nice).

Answer (score 0):

if you are moving from cpanel hosting to another cpanel hosting then just create a full backup of the website that you want to move from WHM which will backed up emails , databases , SSLs , sub domains , addon domains , everything in .tar.gz file format. Download that back up file then upload it to the new servers and restore it from WHM from Restore backup option in WHM.

OR

You can do live migration from WHM itself with Copy Accounts function from WHM which will be easier option to move the websites and the stuff.

However after migration you will need to make sure that you have assigned dedicated IPs , have configured the name servers properly ( the DNS part ) etc..

I would suggest to hire an expert to do this migration in order to avoid any possible issues.